# Is it possible to define an enum in C# such that it is a superset of a different enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I am not attempting to create inheritance between enums, which I understand to be not possible from numerous other questions on SO on the subject.

Rather, I would like to define an enum whose set of names and values contain those of a different enum as well as a few additional name/value definitions.

This is really just for organizational purposes, since it effectively provides no additional functionality that I can think of. However, I think it would be helpful since it lets me imply a sort-of-inheritance between enums in terms of intent (within the source code, presumably post-compile it would no longer be visible). Also, it would save me a small amount of typing and/or copy/pasting.

For example:

```
    public enum ICanCountToThree
    {
        One = 1,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    public enum ICanCountToFive
    {
        ICanCountToThree,
        Four,
        Five
    }
```

In the above code as-is, "ICanCountToThree" is just considered to be a enumeration member name rather than a reference to the enumeration defined directly above it, but I'd like to know if there is some form of syntax that allows the compiler to understand that I want the definitions of One, Two, and Three and then also add in a Four and Five.

Edit: The question that this has been marked as a duplicate of is asking about actual inheritance between enumerations (or at least, it got interpreted that way in the answers). I am only looking for what amounts to a syntactic shorthand (one I suspect does not exist, unfortunately, but would like to verify) wherein the issue of needing to be resolved at compile time is not an issue (the values for both enumerations would be known at compile time and the thing I was looking for would amount to basically an odd form of macro).

I did not find a place in the marked question where what I am asking about is addressed (at least not in an explicit fashion. Perhaps the answers of "no" also encompass this question, but it is not clear because an inability to perform inheritance of enums does not imply the non-existence of the sort of short-hand I was looking for) and the solutions presented in the answers there would be needlessly complex for what I am hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Short answer is "no"; lots more detail in the linked post; you'd have to do this all manually right now

Comment: This may be an alternative you could consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503053/125981 then add to the dictionary as needed